# Via Woocommerce/ Wordpress admin, target the order notes section only to be highlighted

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

I have a client that uses woocommerce with Wordpress. When viewing an order, they wish for any order with notes to be highlighted with a background colour.

When I try and do this, I only seem to be able to target multiple fields within the page, highlighting them all. This is because 'customer notes provided' does not have a class I can target to make the change using a third party plugin that lets you tweak WP backend pages etc.

Without hacking php files, is there a way to just target this field, or add a custom class to it so I can format it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {

  echo '<style>
    #order_data .order_data_column:nth-child(3) .address p:nth-child(2) strong {
        background-color: aqua; /*<-- replace it with your color code*/
    }
  </style>';
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!